# is there a way to solve Python, TypeError: string indices must be integers for data downloaded from yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on building a machine learning model. I got the data in CSV format from yahoo finance. In this code snippet I am trying to figure out the daily moving average, but I am getting a 'Value Error' if try to convert using the code:

```
df[Moving_Average] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(ma).mean()
```

> **MY ACTUAL CODE**
>
> ---
>
> ```
> ma_day = [10,30,50]
> for ma in ma_day:
>     for df in df:
>         Moving_Average = f"MA for {ma} days"
>         df[Moving_Average] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(ma).mean()
> ```

```
 ***THE ERROR***
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) /var/folders/m_/7qrjlgz130q_m51m48k7h0w80000gn/T/ipykernel_1389/3705405762.py in <module>
      6     for df in df:
      7         Moving_Average = f"MA for {ma} days"
----> 8         df[Moving_Average] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(ma).mean()

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `for df in df` is that really a good idea? When you use `df` in the loop, which `df` are you really meaning to use?

Comment: Also why recreate the string `Moving_Average` each time inside the inner loop, when you can just set it once in the outer loop?

Comment: And a [mre] might be good to have as well. Together with a specification of the data you receive into your dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Your for df in df is the problem. Remove it and it works

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import random

df = pd.DataFrame(data=random(100), columns=["Adj Close"])
ma_day = [10, 30, 50]
for ma in ma_day:
    Moving_Average = f"MA for {ma} days"
    rolling = df['Adj Close'].rolling(ma).mean()
    df[Moving_Average] = rolling

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Adj Close  MA for 10 days  MA for 30 days  MA for 50 days
0    0.614659             NaN             NaN             NaN
1    0.464262             NaN             NaN             NaN
2    0.818697             NaN             NaN             NaN
3    0.620061             NaN             NaN             NaN
4    0.277084             NaN             NaN             NaN
..        ...             ...             ...             ...
95   0.921534        0.485049        0.448652        0.510355
96   0.016339        0.409455        0.440603        0.498022
97   0.460253        0.451836        0.439674        0.490771
98   0.421445        0.431691        0.445054        0.490880
99   0.665695        0.494151        0.442298        0.499515

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```